# Is difflib an external package/library for python 3.8?

Tags: difflib

I have got a coursework that I need to complete at the earliest. Coursework has some requirements. One of it is to not use any external package. The coursework is about building a spelling check program. I am using difflib but I am not sure whether it is right to use it or not. Just want to know if it is external package ?

I tried searching on Internet and most of the answers were it is in-built library. So I feel i ca use it but for being sure I am asking.